# Constant enum size no matter the number of enumerated values

Tags: c++, c, enums

Why is the size of an `enum` always 2 or 4 bytes (on a 16- or 32-bit architecture respectively), regardless of the number of enumerators in the type?

Does the compiler treat an `enum` like it does a `union`?

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan: True in C, not in C++ -- and in C, the size of an enum constant can differ from the size of the type.

Comment: @KeithThompson ok I am not sure for C++ also, but in C I am correct ? :)

Comment: @KeithThompson can you please explain about enum types, do you mean we can have enum of type float or double also ? correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: What happens if you create 2,147,483,648 enums?  I bet the compiler gets cranky....

Comment: @KeithThompson please read my comment to @ Adam Rosenfield's answer

Comment: @Jim same is my doubt, one don't wants to create more then 100s symbolic constant. if he do probability he is bad programmer.

Comment: @jhakash: No, you can't have an `enum` of type `float` or `double`; enums are integer types.

Comment: @Jim Just for grins, if you assume the typical uppercase alpha `enum` identifier, and stick to uniform lengths, each identifier would have to be 7 characters, plus a comma and space, which means the source file itself would be on the order of 20GB. I don't expect many compilers would be particularly happy trying to chew through that...

Comment: I HOPE compilers don't check for it.....

Comment: @twalberg" You don't need to define that many identifiers to get an overflow. See my updated answer.

Comment: @twalberg And what about the symbol table that holds all of that?  I strongly suspect something else will break long before you reach that point.

Comment: @LorenPechtel: `enum too_big { big = INT_MAX, bigger };`

Comment: theoretically one can create no more that `INT_MAX` enums constants with different values since `enums` in C behaves like an `int` type.

Comment: @Kira: I'm not sure what's theoretical about that. It's a constraint violation, and gcc at least does diagnose it. See also my answer, and my preceding comment for a way to run into this without defining a huge number of constants.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

In both C and C++, the size of an `enum` type is implementation-defined, and is the same as the size of some integer type.

A common approach is to make all `enum` types the same size as `int`, simply because that's typically the type that makes for the most efficient access. Making it a single byte, for example, would save a very minor amount of space, but could require bigger and slower code to access it, depending on the CPU architecture.

In C, enumeration *constants* are by definition of type `int`. So given:

```
enum foo { zero, one, two };
enum foo obj;
```

the expression `zero` is of type `int`, but `obj` is of type `enum foo`, which may or may not have the same size as `int`. Given that the constants are of type `int`, it tends to be easier to make the enumerated type the same size.

In C++, the rules are different; the constants are of the enumerated type. But again, it often makes the most sense for each `enum` type to be one "word", which is typically the size of `int`, for efficiency reasons.

And the 2011 ISO C++ standard added the ability to specify the underlying integer type for an `enum` type. For example, you can now write:

```
enum foo: unsigned char { zero, one, two };
```

which guarantees that both the type `foo` and the constants `zero`, `one`, and `two` have a size of 1 byte.  C does not have this feature, and it's not supported by older pre-2011 C++ compilers (unless they provide it as a language extension).

(Digression follows.)

So what if you have an enumeration constant too big to fit in an `int`? You don't need 2<sup>31</sup>, or even 2<sup>15</sup>, distinct constants to do this:

```
#include <limits.h>
enum huge { big = INT_MAX, bigger };
```

The value of `big` is `INT_MAX`, which is typically 2<sup>31</sup>-1, but can be as small as 2<sup>15</sup>-1 (32767). The value of `bigger` is implicitly `big + 1`.

In C++, this is ok; the compiler will simply choose an underlying type for `huge` that's big enough to hold the value `INT_MAX + 1`. (Assuming there is such a type; if `int` is 64 bits and there's no integer type bigger than that, that won't be possible.)

In C, since enumeration constants are of type `int`, the above is invalid. It violates the constraint stated in [N1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) 6.7.2.2p2:

> The expression that defines the value of an enumeration constant shall
>   be an integer constant expression that has a value representable as an
>   **int**.

and so a compiler must reject it, or at least warn about it. gcc, for example, says:

> error: overflow in enumeration values

Answer (score 10):

An enum is not a structure, it's just a way of giving names to a set of integers. The size of a variable with this type is just the size of the underlying integer type. This will be a type needed to hold the largest value in the enum. So as long as all the types fit in the same integer type, the size won't change.

Comment: I don't think the OP thought enums were structures. You might expect an `enum` with 256 elements to occupy 8 bits, and one with 257 elements to occupy, say, 16 bits. But compilers commonly make all `enum`s the same size as an `int`, just because that makes for more efficient access.

Comment: @KeithThompson I read it that the OP was looking at enums as struct. In fact his comment mentions that he thought the compiler would treat the enum as a union.

Answer (score 8):

The size of an enum is implementation-defined -- the compiler is allowed to choose whatever size it wants, as long as it's large enough to fit all of the values.  Some compilers choose to use 4-byte enums for all enum types, while some compilers will choose the smallest type (e.g. 1, 2, or 4 bytes) which can fit the enum values.  The C and C++ language standards allow both of these behaviors.

From C99 §6.7.2.2/4:

> Each enumerated type shall be compatible with `char`, a signed integer type, or an
>   unsigned integer type. The choice of type is implementation-defined,<sup>110)</sup> but shall be
>   capable of representing the values of all the members of the enumeration.

From C++03 §7.2/5:

> The *underlying type* of an enumeration is an integral type that can represent all the enumerator values
>   defined in the enumeration. It is implementation-defined which integral type is used as the underlying type
>   for an enumeration except that the underlying type shall not be larger than `int` unless the value of an enumerator
>   cannot fit in an `int` or `unsigned int`. If the *enumerator-list* is empty, the underlying type is
>   as if the enumeration had a single enumerator with value 0. The value of `sizeof()` applied to an enumeration
>   type, an object of enumeration type, or an enumerator, is the value of `sizeof()` applied to the
>   underlying type.

Comment: Good answer but one thing I can't understand why `sizeof(enum) == sizeof(int)` why not `sizeof(char)` One don't like to create `2^sizeof(int)` symbolic constants

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan: `sizeof(enum)` is **not** necessarily equal to the `sizeof(int)`. It could be `sizeof(enum) == sizeof(some integral type)` where `some integral type` depends on the *values* of the enum.

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan: If all of the enum values fit within the range of a `char`, then *it is possible* that you'll have `sizeof(enum) == sizeof(char)`.  There are no guarantees about that, however, it's completely up to the compiler to decide.

Comment: `sizeof(enum) == sizeof(int)` is only true for C. For C++ , its implementation defined.

Comment: @PHIfounder: It's not necessarily true for C either. In both C and C++, the underlying integer type for an `enum` type is implementation-defined; it can be `char` or `unsigned char` as long as all the constants are representable in that type. C enumeration *constants* are of type `int`, but the type itself is not.

Answer (score 3):

It seems to me that the OP has assumed that an enum is some kind of collection which stores the values declared in it. This is incorrect.

An enumeration in C/C++ is simply a numeric variable with strictly defined value range. The names of the enum are kind of aliases for numbers.

The storage size is not influenced by the amount of the values in enumeration. The storage size is implementation defined, but mostly it is the `sizeof(int)`.

Answer (score 1):

The size of an `enum` is "an integral type at least large enough to contain any of the values specified in the declaration". Many compilers will just use an `int` (possibly `unsigned`), but some will use a `char` or `short`, depending on optimization or other factors. An `enum` with less than 128 possible values would fit in a `char` (256 for `unsigned char`), and you would have to have 32768 (or 65536) values to overflow a `short`, and either 2 or 4 billion values to outgrow an `int` on most modern systems.

An `enum` is essentially just a better way of defining a bunch of different constants. Instead of this:

```
#define FIRST 0
#define SECOND 1
...
```

you just:

```
enum myenum
{ FIRST,
  SECOND,
  ...
};
```

It helps avoid assigning duplicate values by mistake, and removes your need to even care what the particular values are (unless you really need to).

Comment: I have a doubt, by defining FIRST 0, does it allocate any memory ?

Comment: @jhakash: No, since that doesn't create an object; it's just a compile-time definition. (BTW, the use of "doubt" to mean "question" tens to be specific to south Asian dialects of English; in US and UK English, "doubt" tends to imply disbelief. "I have a question" would be clearer.

Comment: @KeithThompson Oops. I didn't know about     doubt     thing also, thanks for this clarification also.

Answer (score 0):

The big problem with making an `enum` type smaller than `int` when a smaller type could fit all the values is that it would make the ABI for a translation unit dependent on the number of enumeration constants. For instance, suppose you have a library that uses an `enum` type with 256 constants as part of its public interface, and the compiler chooses to represent the type as a single byte. Now suppose you add a new feature to the library and now need 257 constants. The compiler would have to switch to a new size/representation, and now all object files compiled for the old interface would be incompatible with your updated library; you would have to recompile everything to make it work again.

Thus, any sane implementation always uses `int` for `enum` types.