# Get variable value with an enum type (created by a typedef) in C

Tags: c, enums, typedef

given this definition:

```
typedef enum mytype {
    FIRST = 0,
    TWO = 1,
    Three = 2
} mytype_t;
```

and

```
somefunction(mytype_t param_one) { (some code) }
```

How I can get the integer value of param_one inside the function or assign it to a integer variable?

Comment: `How I can get the integer value of param_one inside the function?` you can simply use `param_one` as you use outside you can also printf it using `%u`

Comment: Read [size of enum is constant no matter how many element it contains](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17888322/size-of-enum-is-constant-no-matter-how-many-element-it-contains/17888598#17888598)

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan note that this title is misleading and it is acceptable to have for example `sizeof (enum bla) != sizeof (enum blop)` in one particular implementation.

Comment: @ouah I learned from linked Q&A that in **C** `sizeof(enum constant) == sizeof(int)` whereas not necessary in C++. So is it implementation dependent?

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan an `enum` constant is of type `int` but each `enum` type is an implementation-defined integer type.

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan: Why `%u` rather than `%d`? It's perfectly legal for an enumeration constant to be negative: `enum foo { a=-1, b=0, c=1 };`

Comment: @KeithThompson Oh yes `%d` is correct. But what @ouah message in last comment not clear to me.

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan: In the example in the question, `FIRST` is a constant expression of type `int`, but `enum mytype` is a distinct type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just use it - it is an integer type already:

```
int x = param_one;
```

Comment: Sorry I didn't thought it was so easy. But I didn't find the answer on Google. Thanks for your fast one, but I can't vote up it.

Comment: @user2284570 But you can accept it. Apart from that: you should be consulting a beginner C tutorial and/or language reference.